# Using data as Lists or Arrays in ASP.NET Web API response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, collections

When I receive data from a database in my ASP.NET Web API, I generally call them in form of a List if expect to receive multiple entries. So this is fine because LINQ provides some cool methods for work with Lists.

But my question is, I have seen some developers set the API controller to send the response to the client as List. I'm wondering is there any special reason not to use Arrays when sending JSON response to the client because, apparently there is no difference between JSON strings that serialized from Arrays or Lists.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JSONArray internally uses an ArrayList so it's just like wrapper over ArrayList. I would say that there is no significant difference between ArrayList and JSONArray. JSONObject uses HashMap internally.

As for Collections, LinkedListis the fastest, by which the most efficient way would be to use LinkedList with JSONObject instead of JSONArrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, there is no difference between returning an array or a list from the API, in JSON both will end up as an array. So just return the form that your data is in.